# creating Configurable products shows products for only one attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to create a configurable product. I have created 3 attributes and assigned the simple products to each of them. When I want to create a configurable product, if I choose only one of the attributes, the simple products are shown in the "Associated Products".

But if I choose multiple attributes, no products is shown in the "Associated Products" tab. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Three attributes you created should be also present in all the three simple product that you have created

Comment: Thank you, It is now working but this way I have to create many simple products.

Comment: if you don't want to mange  inventory for each option then you can look for "custom option " in products